# Quicktime Screen Recording doesn't work in Lion

Tags: macos, screen-capture, quicktime, recording

When starting a new Screen Recording in Quicktime Player in Lion 10.7.3, as soon as I click record I get this following error message:

[image: quicktime error]

Here's a video demonstrating the issue: http://db.tt/CROyXgIt

Here are the settings under the triangle on the right:

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me. Just putting that out there.

Comment: May I ask, though, what's the input-bar-type thing between the O and N of operation? Also, there's usually correct punctuation in Apple's error messages (i.e. "The operation could not be completed." with a period). What's up?

Comment: The input-bar-type thing is just a cursor that appears if you click on the message. the message isn't editable or anything, though. When I take a screenshot, the main quicktime window disappears, even with a full screenshot - http://i.imgur.com/Lokhm.png?1 (that screenshot shows you can select text with the cursor thing)

Comment: Huh, never seen that before. OK!

Comment: @penguinrob What are your settings under the triangle on the right?

Comment: @KyleCronin added to the question

Comment: @penguinrob Hm, nothing unusual there. This is pretty bizarre. Maybe try creating a new user account and seeing if you still get the problem there? If you do, maybe it's a HDCP issue with the monitor you're using, but I'm otherwise at a loss here.

Comment: @KyleCronin Just tried it in a guest account and it works great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally figured it out - apparently the Movies folder in my home directory had a weird permission set on it and things couldn't be written to it, which caused QuickTime to give a very descriptive message "The operation could not be completed" and saving to a different folder (or after fixing the permissions on Movies), worked.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your question as answered !

Comment: What did you set the permissions to?

Comment: @nipponese The permissions were set to "Read only" for my user account, so I changed it to "Read & Write" for my account in the Finder Get Info window, and then I could save to it.

Comment: doesn't work, permission «Read & Write», macOS: 10.12.4, QuickTime Player: 10.4, iOS: 10.3.1

Answer (score 1):

Simply restarting my mac worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I ran into this issue today and the problem was with the external monitor. After unplugging the Apple Display, I was able to see the phone screen output fine.